# Grothendieck's Generic Freeness Lemma: Step in proof from Vakil's FOAG

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, modules

I'm trying to solve the following exercise (7.4.K) from Vakil's FOAG, which is a step in the proof of Grothendieck's Generic Freeness Lemma:

[image]

Here's my attempt:

We proceed by induction on $n$ to construct the compatible isomorphisms $\phi_n$ as in the exercise. We have an exact sequence
$$0\to M_{n-1}\to M_n\to M_n/M_{n-1}\to 0$$
Since $M_n/M_{n-1}$ is free by assumption, it is projective and thus the exact sequence above splits. As a result we have $M_n\cong M_{n-1}\oplus M_{n}/M_{n-1}$ and a right inverse to the projection $M_n\to M_n/M_{n-1}$. Call this map $\psi_n$. Next, define $\phi_n$ to be $\phi_{n-1}$ on $M_{n-1}\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^{i= n-1} M_i/M_{i-1}$ and $\psi_n$ on $M_{n}/M_{n-1}$, and extend linearly. As a result we see that the maps $\phi_n$ are compatible in the sense that the diagram

[image]

commutes.

We take colimits to obtain a unique map $\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb{N}} M_i/M_{i-1}\to M$. Similarly, we get a unique map in the opposite direction, working with the inverses of the $\phi_n$'s. Combining these, we see that $\bigoplus M_i/M_{i-1}\cong M$, whence it follows that $M$ itself is free.

I would be very grateful is someone could verify if what I've said makes sense, or point out where I've messed up.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say 'working with the inverses of the $\phi_n'$s'...$\phi_n$ only has a left inverse and not a right one.

Comment: @Evans Gambit But the $\phi_n$'s are isomorphisms right?

Comment: I suppose, it will need some argument to show that $\phi_n$ are isomorphisms by induction on $n$.

Comment: @EvansGambit doesn't my argument already show that? Indeed, I've shown $M_n \cong M_{n-1} \oplus M_n/M_{n-1}$, and $\phi_n$ is basically just this isomorphism?

Comment: Ohh...you are right. It does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hypotheses imply that for every $i \ge 1$ there exists $N_i \subset M_i$, $N_i \simeq M_i/M_{i-1}$ such that
$$M_i = M_{i-1} \oplus N_i$$
(interior direct sum)
and so
$$M_i = N_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus N_i$$
for all $i \ge 1$
Now we get
$$\varinjlim M_i \simeq \oplus_{i\ge 1} N_i$$

Answer (score 2):

TO show the map $$\Phi:\oplus_{n=1}^{\infty}M_n/M_{n-1}\to M$$ is isomorphism.

**First $\Phi$ is surjective**:  We show that $M_n\subset Im(\psi)$ by induction on $n\geq 1$.

In $n=1$,then since $\phi_1=Id$ we are fine.

Let $n>1$:
Let $0\neq a\in M$ such that $a\in M_n$ and $a\notin M_{n-1}$.

Then $\phi_n(\bar{a})-a\mapsto 0$ under $M_n\to M_n/M_{n-1}$. So  $\phi_n(\bar{a})-a\in M_{n-1}$ So $a=\phi_n(\bar{a})+(a-\phi_n(\bar{a}))$.

Now $a-\phi_n(\bar{a})\in M_{n-1}\subset Im(\psi)$ bu induction hypothesis.

Thus $a=\phi_n(\bar{a})+(a-\phi_n(\bar{a}))\subset Im(\psi).$

Similarly, we can show **$\Phi$ is injective**.